# Is it possible to get the current spark context settings in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, config, pyspark

I'm trying to get the path to `spark.worker.dir` for the current `sparkcontext`.

If I explicitly set it as a `config param`, I can read it back out of `SparkConf`, but is there anyway to access the complete `config` (including all defaults) using `PySpark`?

Comment: No - you can get the conf object but not the things you'd looking for. Defaults are not available through `SparkConf` (they're hardcoded in the sources). And `spark.worker.dir` sounds like a configuration for the Worker daemon, not something your app would see.

Comment: My answer directly addresses your question : please provide feedback

Comment: Landed here trying to find out the value for `spark.default.parallelism`. It is at `sc.defaultParallelism`. One can do `dir(sc)` in PySpark to see what's available in `sc`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yes:  **sc.getConf().getAll()**

Which uses the method:

```
SparkConf.getAll()
```

as accessed by

```
SparkContext.sc.getConf()
```

See it in action:

```
    In [4]: sc.getConf().getAll()
    Out[4]:
    [(u'spark.master', u'local'),
     (u'spark.rdd.compress', u'True'),
     (u'spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', u'100'),
     (u'spark.app.name', u'PySparkShell')]
```

Comment: also, note that the underscore means that the package developers think that accessing this data element isn't a great idea.

Comment: "Note that only values explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf, or the command line will appear. For all other configuration properties, you can assume the default value is used." (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#viewing-spark-properties)

Comment: @asmaier any idea how I can get these non-appearing ones to appear in python without having to go to a web page? E.g. how do I get the value of "spark.default.parallelism"?

Comment: `error: variable _conf in class SparkContext cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.SparkContext` - that's what spark-shell answers in Spark 2.4. Has this variable gone private since the answer?

Comment: @Cerberus May be so - and `.getConf` should be used instead

Comment: This answer was edited to use `.getConf` instead of `._conf`, which makes the part about "Note the Underscore..." not make sense anymore.

Comment: in Spark3 I found that the brackets aren't needed so it's `sc.getConf.getAll`

Comment: This is one of the most confusing accepted answers I've seen. Please someone who understands it, edit it to be easier to follow

Comment: One line to have pretty print: `print(json.dumps(dict(sc.getConf().getAll()), indent=4, sort_keys=True))`.

Answer (score 138):

Spark 2.1+

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
```

In the above code, `spark` is your `sparksession` (gives you a `dict` with all configured settings)

Comment: @hhantyal no. When the question was asked there was no spark2.1. The top answer works for all versions of spark, especially old ones

Comment: for spark 2.4.0, it returns a list of tuples instead of a dict

Comment: @Kevad we are using a Spark 2.4, so can you please throw some light on the following code `spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()` 
spark - The SparkSession
sparkContext - (As we already have the SparkSession from verion 2.0+ what does this sparkContext imply)
Could you please help me get a deeper insight on this ?

Comment: returns ``tuples`` not ``dict``

Comment: I don't thinks this statement also return all the hadoop configuration.

Answer (score 37):

update configuration in **Spark 2.3.1**

To change the default spark configurations you can follow these steps:

**Import the required classes**

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

**Get the default configurations**

```
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
```

**Update the default configurations**

```
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '4g'), ('spark.app.name', 'Spark Updated Conf'), ('spark.executor.cores', '4'), ('spark.cores.max', '4'), ('spark.driver.memory','4g')])
```

**Stop the current Spark Session**

```
spark.sparkContext.stop()
```

**Create a Spark Session**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Hello Bob, I got a question about this. If you get the config via:
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
How can you then use that result to update the config with including new settings.
I think this would be a nice addition to your answer.

Comment: @PaulVelthuis: to include new settings you need to restart the spark context with your updated conf. its there in answer, after updating the conf, we stopped the context and started again with new conf.

Answer (score 34):

Spark 1.6+

```
sc.getConf.getAll.foreach(println)
```

Comment: 1.6.3: >>> sc.getConf.getAll.foreach(println) 

AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'getConf'

Comment: @dovka - I used the same `sc.getConf.getAll.foreach(println)` as suggested by @ecesena and it worked fine for me (in Scala) - Perhaps the syntax is not for Python?

Comment: Not in pyspark 1.6.0 as you can see here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext

Answer (score 20):

For a complete overview of your Spark environment and configuration I found the following code snippets useful:

SparkContext:

```
for item in sorted(sc._conf.getAll()): print(item)
```

Hadoop Configuration:

```
hadoopConf = {}
iterator = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().iterator()
while iterator.hasNext():
    prop = iterator.next()
    hadoopConf[prop.getKey()] = prop.getValue()
for item in sorted(hadoopConf.items()): print(item)
```

Environment variables:

```
import os
for item in sorted(os.environ.items()): print(item)
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply running

```py
sc.getConf().getAll()
```

should give you a list with all settings.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, no, the Spark platform as of version 2.3.1 does not provide any way to programmatically access the value of every property at run time. It provides several methods to access the values of properties that were explicitly set through a configuration file (like `spark-defaults.conf`), set through the `SparkConf` object when you created the session, or set through the command line when you submitted the job, but none of these methods will show the default value for a property that was not explicitly set. For completeness, the best options are:

- The Spark application’s web UI, usually at `http://<driver>:4040`, has an “Environment” tab with a property value table.
- The `SparkContext` keeps a hidden reference to its configuration in PySpark, and the configuration provides a `getAll` method: `spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()`.
- Spark SQL provides [the `SET` command](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/set.html) that will return a table of property values: `spark.sql("SET").toPandas()`. You can also use `SET -v` to include a column with the property’s description.

(These three methods all return the same data on my cluster.)

Answer (score 7):

For Spark 2+ you can also use when using scala

```
spark.conf.getAll; //spark as spark session
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
sc.sparkContext.getConf.getAll
```

For example, I often have the following at the top of my Spark programs:

```
logger.info(sc.sparkContext.getConf.getAll.mkString("\n"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose I want to increase the driver memory in runtime using Spark Session:

```
s2 = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "29g").getOrCreate()
```

Now I want to view the updated settings:

```
s2.conf.get("spark.driver.memory")
```

To get all the settings, you can make use of `spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()`

[image: UPDATED SETTINGS]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Just for the records the analogous java version:

```
Tuple2<String, String> sc[] = sparkConf.getAll();
for (int i = 0; i < sc.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(sc[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can get all the default settings easily, but specifically for the worker dir, it's quite straigt-forward:

```
from pyspark import SparkFiles
print SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the configuration in data bricks use the below command

```
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try the method below in order to get the current spark context settings.

```
SparkConf.getAll()
```

as accessed by

```
SparkContext.sc._conf
```

Get the default configurations specifically for Spark 2.1+

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
```

Stop the current Spark Session

```
spark.sparkContext.stop()
```

Create a Spark Session

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```