# How to get the parameters I pass in spark-submit command in python

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-submit

I am using spark-submit command to run a python code using pyspark.

Something like:

`spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 15 --executor-cores 6 test.py`

Is there any way I can get the parameters I am using in the spark-submit command in python e.g get 15 and 6 as variables and if I use other numbers get those numbers.

Comment: have you tried `import os` and looking in `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the current spark context settings in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560241/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-spark-context-settings-in-pyspark)