# Print all config properties of a SparkSession / SparkContext in Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark

How do I print all config properties of a SparkSession / SparkContext in in Jupyter?

Answer (score 1):

Assume `spark` is an instance of `SparkSession`, and `sc` is an instance of `SparkContext`,

### Scala

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf.getAll.foreach(println)
```

or

```
sc.getConf.getAll.foreach(println)
```

### Python

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
```

or

```
sc.getConf().getAll()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560241/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-spark-context-settings-in-pyspark